# Understanding ArcGIS Online Unable to load ... status: 413 error?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online

I am trying to load .shp file to arcgis.com online. I put it to zip file and has .dbf .prj .qpj .shp .shx files in zip. It can be opened in QGIS, CartoDB, but when I trying to import arcgis online.

(My Content -> Add Item -> From My Computer), it gives

> Unable to load
>
> http://[my_address].maps.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/users/[myuser]/addItem
>
> status: 413

[image]

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: This has been cross-posted from http://stackoverflow.com/q/31355635

Answer (score 7):

If you have a look at the [HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes), you can find that a HTTP 413 means "Request Entity Too Large" - The request is larger than the server is willing or able to process.

Probably you can export partial content in QGIS to a separate .shp file and try uploading again, to ensure, it has nothing to do with your data.

**EDIT:** This [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/116807/uploading-large-files-to-arconline) claims, there is a limit of 1000 features per file to be uploaded to arcgis online.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing that exact problem even saving maps online. Here is what worked for me.

1. Log into the server (hosting server) with administrator privileges
2. Open the **cmd** (command window) and type **%windir%\System32**
3. Then look for the folder named **intesrv** and open it
4. Right click inside this folder and choose **Open windows command here**
5. Execute the following command, swapping  for a desired value in bytes:
   **appcmd.exe set config -section:system.WebServer/serverRuntime /uploadReadAheadSize: ""**
6. Then restart the IIS using the following command. Rebooting the Server is not required.
   **iisreset**